# How to connect in Hive using Java?

Tags: java, hive

I'm trying to find a way to **connect my web app to Hive by using Java**. Does anybody here know how to do it? I have no idea and experience in doing it and there are not enough tutorials and step-by-step process available on the net. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many tutorials which will tell you step by step [like this](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-jdbc-client-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:<port>/<dbname>", "<user>", "<password>");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet res = sql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename");
```

This is a sample HIVE connection code. You need to add "HiveDriver" jar to the class path

Comment: Thanks for this Chamara, but apparently, i have this error code below

" Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://<IP_HOST>:<PORT>/default: Invalid status 72" 

What should be done to fix this?

Comment: Issue 72 - This happened due to the your connection url is wrong or bad. Try to add transport mode to the connection string "transportMode=http"

Comment: Make Sure that you have hiveserver2 running. Go to HIve installed folder. hit below command: 

bin/hive --service hiveserver2